# How can I know whether I am a Google One member?

Tags: google, google-one

Google sent me this email:

> Summary of the new policies (effective June 1, 2021): If you're inactive for 2 years (24 months) in Gmail, Drive or Photos, we may delete the content in the product(s) in which you're inactive. **Google One members** who are within their storage quota and in good-standing **will not be impacted by this new inactive policy**.

How can I know whether I am a Google One member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first result when I Google’d “google one”
was https://one.google.com/about,
which seems to indicate that it’s an enhanced / elevated service plan,
where you pay money for lots of storage
(starting at 100 GB) and access to a help desk.

So, if you’re paying money to Google for a membership,
then you’re a member, and if you’re not, then you’re not.

Comment: got it, I got confused by the fact that Google distinguishes Google One **users** from Google One **members**. So currently I am a user but not a member.

Answer (score 0):

Google distinguishes Google One **users** from Google One **members**, as currently displayed on https://one.google.com/home:

> As a free **Google One user**, you can back up data on your phone, and also free up space in your Google Account using the storage manager. If you get a **Google One membership**, you’ll unlock additional features like expanded cloud storage, support from our team of Google experts, and exclusive benefits.

As [G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica'](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/173377/g-man-says-reinstate-monica)'s [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149548/18147) mentions, Google One **memberships** are paid only.